# How to configure local Apache configuration to deny access to non index directories?

Tags: windows, security, apache-http-server

I am configuring a new Apache installation in my PC to mirror my configuration a online shared server.

I do not want users to have access to my directories without `index.*` files so I included `httpd.conf` the `Options -Indexes` to do that task, but now I can't restart the Apache Service (in Windows 7 64bit).

Only after removing that line I am able to restart Apache.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and what should I do to make the correct configuration?

```
DocumentRoot "C:\dropbox\Servidores\Web"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    # Options –Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\dropbox\Servidores\Web">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. uncomment the `Options –Indexes` lines - then you will have the configuration what you want.
2. then start command line (`cmd.exe`) and go to Apache's `bin` directory (`..\httpd\bin`)
3. start the command `httpd.exe -t` (it will test your Apache configuration)
4. then you will see the errors and you can write it here to better analyze your problem

Maybe you will see this:

```
Illegal option \x96Indexes
```

If yes, there is a bad character before `Indexes` - try to delete it and write again manually.